# Launch Screen image - universal pixel sizes?

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I'm having trouble setting my launch screen image (not a image that fills the entire page i.e., not a splash screen) that works on all the iOS products (iPhone, iPad to name some).

I would like to know the universal pixel or point sizes for each set - 1x, 2x, 3x. As far as my google search goes, assets catalog creator seems to be the solution. But are there any alternates?

Comment: use vector images see this http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this. I'm using xcode 7 and it askes for three images of various pixel sizes namely 1x, 2x, 3x. As i read through your link these are the ones i found relevent enough. Are these your suggestions as well?? -> 1x PNG at 150px x 150px
-> 2x PNG at 300px x 300px
-> 3x PNG at 450px x 450px

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!!

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. You talk about wanting launch screen images but then you say not full screen splash screen images. Those are the same thing. Please clarify what images you are really talking about.

Comment: They both are the same thing? As i said before, i'm new to this. I just want the image to fill in a small portion of the launch screen.

Comment: then put that image in `assets` with 1x,2x and 3x sizes. (for example : 150,300,450). And use that image to fill that small imageview of your lauchscreen!!

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I read the [blog post](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/). I made two sample project who uses vector and scalar graphics individually. however the size of application and Assets.car is same on both projects. So does vector graphics usage helps in reducing the app size or not. PS: I am very interested to learn about app size minimisation tricks.